# Passing fullname variable to PHP session

Tags: php, javascript

How do i set the `response.name` value to `$_SESSION`

```
  FB.api('/me', function (response) {
    var fullname = response.name;
    <?php $_SESSION['fullname'] = 'fullname'; ?>
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to run server side code using data gained by running client side code, then you must send the data to the server. The data won't have been collected at the time the server side code that generates the client side runs.

You could use a redirect (`location = etc etc`) or Ajax (there are plenty of tutorials out there) to do this.

Answer (score 5):

## Why You need a ajax call?

PHP is server side scripting and can't be used in client-side scripting like Javascript. But you can make an AJAX call to server and set your session :)

.

```
    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
    var fullname = response.name;
    $.ajax({ 
       url : "setsession.php?name="+fullname,
       cache : false,
       type : POST;
    });
  });
```

setsession.php:

```
<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['fullname'] = $_GET['name']; ?>
```

Comment: downvoters please i have corrected my mistake, you can now remove downvote now!

Comment: my pleasure to help you :D